# SQL count limiting results

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo

I'm having an issue with following query:

```
SELECT 
   badge.name AS badge_name, badge.description, badge.type, badges.time, user.name AS user_name 
FROM 
   badges LEFT JOIN badge ON badges.badge_name = badge.name LEFT JOIN user ON user.id=badges.user_id 
WHERE 
   user.name IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY badges.time DESC 
LIMIT 5
```

Now, I'd like to check that the amount of results is not 0, so I check like I always do with by adding this after the `SELECT`: `count(1) AS counter`. However, this influences the results.

[How it should be](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7ae77/5).

[How it is with the count.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7ae77/6)

I've seen that this might be an issue due to also having a `LIMIT`, but what's the most efficient way to circumvent this? I just want to check whether there are any results returned or not, to display a proper message it there are no results. I'm using `PDO`, but since it's a `SELECT` i can't use the `->rowCount()` to check the amount of rows returned.

**EDIT:**

I want to determine whether there are any results, yes or no. My *normal* way of doing so is using `count(1) AS counter`, and checking the value of the counter as follows:

```
while($row['counter'] = $STH->fetch()){
    if($row['counter'] == 0){
        // Error message
    }else{
        echo $row['badge_name'] . "etc...";
    }
}
```

*However*, this seems to mess up the results due to the `LIMIT` (check the SQLFiddles).

So: how can I check this, preferably in a single query?

Comment: I suggest that you explain what you are trying to do. Based on what I can understand is that you want to get the resultset, but at the same time you want some way to determine if no rows were returned. If it's returns a collection, I would have guessed that you can certainly interrogate the count, but I'm not a PHP guy. I recommend that you rewrite your requirement so people can better understand.

Comment: @RobertCo I've edited my answer to clarify myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I'm not personally familiar with MySQL features covering this I would normally make it a comment on your question but I don't have the required rep yet.  So, I have to make it an "answer".

It sounds like you want the equivalent of T-SQL's @@ROWCOUNT.  From what I can find that's talked about here

[Does Mysql have an equivalent to @@ROWCOUNT like in mssql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229218/what-is-mysql-version-of-rowcount)

and here

[obtain row count in mysql query itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4241752/obtain-row-count-in-mysql-query-itself)

Maybe some of that is of use to you.

Comment: Your first link indeed links to a correct solution, using `SELECT ROW_COUNT();` in a new query is more efficient than doing a whole query and counting the results.

Answer (score 1):

Add `count(*) as count` to count number of rows.

```
SELECT
   count(*) as `count`
FROM
   badges LEFT JOIN badge ON badges.badge_name = badge.name LEFT JOIN user ON user.id=badges.user_id
WHERE
   user.name IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: This seems to [also return one result](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7ae77/16) whilst there are [two expected](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7ae77/5)

Comment: @arbitter Do you want to know how many records you have on table by query?

Comment: I just want to check whether there is a result or not. In normal situations, the table should be saturated and 5 records should be a minimum. But in case something happens and it suddenly drops to 0, I'd like to say that there are no results instead of having just nothing.

Comment: I updated the answer. It return number of rows as `count` if exist any.

Comment: Okay I've made myself a bit unclear again - I'd also want to get the results of the table as well, not only the count. Is it possible to do this in a single query?

Comment: Why not? Adding a second query seems a bit unnecessary since that would require double the resources. Reading into other questions like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125966/sql-count-total-number-of-rows-whilst-using-limit), it seems that using `SELECT  FOUND_ROWS();` is also a valid option, without the need of a second query.

Comment: @arbitter I think It's not good idea to add count of all records as a `field` in results. Run your sql as yourself `whihout count(*)` to get data. Also It will be clean to get number of record by PDO `rowCount()` method